# How can I create an Ad Account in the Facebook Ads API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

In the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-api/objects) they say how to create every single object except for an Ad Account. On the Ad Account Group page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adaccountgroup) they say how to add an Ad Account to an Ad Account Group, but that uses an already existing Ad Account ID. All the objects below an Ad Account (Ad Campaign, Ad Set, etc.) need to have an Ad Account exist first, but I cannot find how to make one.

Any help? I feel like this should be simple but I am having so much trouble.

Comment: You can't, you need to create the ad account using Facebook's frontend- create it,  add billing information to the account, etc

Comment: Several years have passed, is it now possible to create an ad account using their api?